# Why is MessageDlg not shown after a form is freed via OnClose event (in a thread)

Tags: multithreading, delphi, dialog, delphi-xe6

Given this scenario:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Form: TForm;
begin
  Form := TForm.Create(nil);
  Form.OnClose := FormClosed;
  Form.Show;
  Sleep(200);
  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
      TThread.Synchronize( nil, 
        procedure 
        begin 
          Form.Close; 
          MessageDlg('Testing', mtInformation, [mbok], 0); 
        end);
    end).Start;
end;

procedure TForm2.FormClosed(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := TCloseAction.caFree;
end;
```

My MessageDlg call is not displayed (the result of this call is always `mrCancel` (2)).

After digging around, it's related to the OnClose event and setting the Action to caFree.

Changing `Form.Close` to `Form.Free` and removing the OnClose event entirely displays MessageDlg ok.  Placing MessageDlg *before* the call to Form.Close works ok.  Originally I thought scope of my Form variable might have caused the problem but declaring `Form`as a private field in TForm2 instance doesn't solve the problem.

My aim was to display a splash form, execute my thread, then through call backs of said thread, close the Splash form and display dialog where appropriate to the user.

For clarity, why does this occur?

Comment: If you look, I'm calling TThread.Synchronize... Unless I can't call it like that, apology accepted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is happening is that the dialog's owning window is the form that is being closed. When the dialog starts its modal message loop, the form is released and takes down its owned windows with it. Including the dialog.

Test this out, to give you more confidence that what I state above is correct, by replacing the call to show the dialog first with

```
MessageBox(0, ...);
```

and then with

```
MessageBox(Form.Handle, ...);
```

That is, be explicit about the dialog's owner.

The first version, with no owner, will show the dialog. The second won't because it replicates the scenario in your code.

Comment: I traced and verify this to be the case. Modify LParentWnd in TCustomTaskDialog.Execute to be 0  by the debugger, and the dialog is shown. Otherwise the dialog gets the active window as its owner, which is then pulled under its foot.

Comment: @David, since your hunch has proven to be accurate, might I suggest that you edit your answer to remove the apparent uncertainty  and make it clearer that this is indeed the case ?  (I didn't wish to presume to edit it myself).  :)

Comment: Just that the poster does not miss the obvious solution: put a `SetFocus` call after `Form.Close`, and the active window will be  the TForm2 instance in the question when the message dialog is shown.

Answer (score 3):

The Windows runtime requires that the messages for a visual window be processed by a message loop running in the same thread that creates that window.

The Windows API's also enforce rules about what operations can be performed on a window from a thread other than that in which the window was created.  i.e. very little indeed, other than sending or posting messages to it.

With that information in mind, we can explain what is occurring in your case.

The **Form.Close** method ultimately closes a form by posting it a message (`CM_RELEASE`).  But in your implementation the message loop responsible for responding to that message - the application main message loop - is blocked as a result of the fact that the message is posted from within a **Synchronize()** method.

i.e. your Synchronize()d method posts the message to close the form, but that message cannot and will not be processed by that forms window until your Synchronize()d method has completed, and that will not occur until the user has responded to the message box you are presenting in that method.

I hope that helps you understand what is going on in your code.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, thanks.  However, not sure I understand how it applies to what my problem is.  The form not closing is not the problem.  It's the fact that MessageDlg is not showing at all so it's not waiting until the user has responded to the message box, there is no message box in the first place.  So is it that the Form.Close method (via the CM_RELEASE message) is interfering with the MessageDlg (form)?  Have I missed the point?

Comment: I see - sorry, I misunderstood slightly.  But as David has highlighted in his answer, the underlying issue is still which thread "owns" the window(s) involved.  As a general rule I would say that it's best to keep all UI interactions in the main thread and ensure that any additional threads are entirely non-visual (and don't use Synchronize() - it is the devil's work).  It encourages a belief that it solves all UI/threading problems when it does not.  Learn about and use proper thread synchronization using events, mutexes etc and how Windows messages work in the presence of threads.

Comment: I don't think that's really relevant. The exact same issue arises in an app with no threads.

Comment: @David, Ack, yes of course.  Re-entrancy being the issue rather than threading, thanks to that ShowModal message loop.